# Error on Node-sass when trying to compile resources with npm and webpack o laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, sass

I am trying to compile resources on a laravel 5.4 project, but everytime I run `npm run watch` I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: 
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: 
Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
```

My linux version is 4.15.0-23-generic
Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I actually just used `npm install -f node-sass` and that fixed it.